# C code frequency table using acsii.

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to C programming, its my 6th week in class so far i haven't had any major issues. I just cant figure out were i'm going wrong with my current assignment and its due in just a couple hours. Here is what i have so far. i'm using visual studio 2012.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char textChar;
int textLenght = 0;
int asciiArray[128] = {0};
int i;

int main()
{
printf("Enter a line of text: ");
scanf("%d", &textChar);

while ((textChar = getchar())!= '\n') {
textLenght++;
asciiArray[textChar]++;
}
printf("\nFREQUENCY TABLE\n");
 printf("---------------\n");
 printf("Char Count %% of Total\n");
 printf("---- ----- ----------\n");
 printf(" ALL %5d %9.2f%%\n", textLenght,( textLenght * 100.0 ) / textLenght );

 for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
     if( asciiArray[textChar] != 0 )
    printf("%c %d %9.2f%% \n",i+ "0",asciiArray[textChar]);

 getchar();
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Now i know there is a problem within my for loop because its not displaying, I'm just not sure if there are other problems besides that. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: well what do you think `( textLenght * 100.0 ) / textLenght` is gonna output, in first place? `100`. Always. No matter what `textLength` is.

Comment: Also, don't use `scanf()`. It's horrible and equally horribly hard to use correctly. You **just** got it wrong. When you scan `textChar` (WHY?? I don't even see its purpose...), then after scanning an integer, `scanf()` will leave the newline character in the input buffer, and so your first call to `getchar()` will immediately return it, causing your loop to terminate. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Textchar is \n you never updated it. And length is usually gth.

Comment: Visual Studio has a great great debugger. Just hit F10 and step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read documentation of every function you are using. Notice that [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) return a useful result (count of scanned items).

Answer (score 0):

This line is not right.

```
scanf("%d", &textChar);
```

1. It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish with this line.
2. When you use `%d` as the format specifier, the function will try to read an integer and store it at the given address. Since type of `textChar` is not `int`, you are going to run into undefined behavior right away.

Instead of using `getchar`, which is not a standard C library function, you should use `fgetc(stdin)`.

`fgetc()` returns an `int`. Make sure to change the type of `textChar` to int.

Change the lines:

```
printf("Enter a line of text: ");
scanf("%d", &textChar);

while ((textChar = getchar())!= '\n') {
textLenght++;
asciiArray[textChar]++;
}
```

to

```
printf("Enter a line of text: ");

while ((textChar = fgetc(stdin))!= '\n') {
textLenght++;
asciiArray[textChar]++;
}
```

I would remove the last two calls to `getchar()`. They don't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: For the first line i was attempting to store the value of the string entered. What needs to be stored according to the assignment is this "THIS IS a test of string 0123456789  +~_!)@()#($*%&^ stuff" and my desired out put is, the frequency and percentage.

Comment: @kcg, that's not going work. 1. You need to use `%s` to read a string. 2. You need provide a pointer to a string, not a pointer to one `char`. 3. If you use `%s`, `scanf` will stop at the first whitespace character. `fgets()` is a better function to read a line of text.